# Increment value of input through classes

Tags: jquery, button, increment

I want to make a button to increment de value of differents inputs.
Then I thought the best way would be to create a class and eliminating it . Once I create the class I can not access it .
If I click the button does nothing.

```
var valorDipVl = Number($('#dip-vl').val());
var valorForiaVl = Number($('#foriaVl').val());    

$('#dip-vl').on('focus',function() {
    $('#arriba>button').removeClass().addClass('activo');
})
$('#foriaVl').on('focus',function() {
    $('#arriba>button').removeClass().addClass('activo2');
})

$('button.activo').on('click', function() {
    valorDipVl += 1;
    $('#dip-vl').attr('value', valorDipVl);
})
$('button.activo2').on('click', function() {
    valorForiaVl+=1;
    $('#foriaVl').attr('value', valorForiaVl);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click functions needs delegating:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.activo', function() {
   // Code
});
```

[Jquery Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)